# How to set vim keymappings?

Tags: vimrc

I am tryng to use https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors,

```
" Default mapping
let g:multi_cursor_start_word_key      = '<C-n>'
let g:multi_cursor_select_all_word_key = '<A-n>'
let g:multi_cursor_start_key           = 'g<C-n>'
let g:multi_cursor_select_all_key      = 'g<A-n>'
let g:multi_cursor_next_key            = '<C-n>'
let g:multi_cursor_prev_key            = '<C-p>'
let g:multi_cursor_skip_key            = '<C-x>'
let g:multi_cursor_quit_key            = '<Esc>'
```

What does each of these mean? I presses Ctrl + n, and nothing gets selected. What am I missing?